# Trying to get property of non-object - name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

i am trying to print the username, but it gives me error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Models

**User**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\Registro;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function registros(){
      
       
         return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Registro', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Registro**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \App\Models\User;

class Registro extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\User');

    }
   
}
```

**database:**

[image]

in blade.php:

```
  {{$registro->user_id->name}}
```

maybe I'm doing something wrong with relationships, but I can't figure it out on my own

```
<tbody class="list">
            @foreach($registros as $registro)
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                  <div class="media align-items-center">
                    <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                      <img alt="Image placeholder" src="../../assets/img/theme/bootstrap.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <span class="name mb-0 text-sm">{{$registro->user_id->name}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
            
              </tr>
             @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

try changed relationships but it doesn't work
does not allow me to print the name of user_id, help pls

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing user detail wrongly. It should be

```
{{$registro->user->name}}
```

Here `user` is `relationship` name which is defined in `Registro`  model

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship is hasMany user, so when you access it you get a collection. In that way you need loop that collection to get the desired user model